# How to do Loop to read row one by one if exist for duplicate data for VBA Macro and put msg box?

Tags: vba, excel

How to do Loop to read row one by one if exist for duplicate data for VBA Macro and put message box?

```
No  Campaign    TL  Location of Scanned Document

1   *adrian adrian  adrian*
2   *adrian adrian  adrian*
```

Comment: To format code and other pre-formatted text, select it and press Ctrl+K

Answer (score 1):

This checked for duplicates in Column A amend the A to any other column you would like to check

```
Sub DupeCheck()

For i = 1 to Range("A" & Range("A" & rows.count).end(xlUp).row)
  if Range("A" & i).value = Range("A" & i+1).value then
    msgbox "Duplicate Record found in Row " & i & ". Duplicate Value is : " & Range("A" & i+1).value
  end if
Next i

End Sub
```